# Clone VM with new CloudService, VNet and Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I try to clone an existing VM.
Requirements:

- new cloud service
- new VNet
- new storage account

So at first I captured my existing VM.
Now here are my 4 tries which didn't work:

1. Create via preview portal:
   -> not possible because you can't create a VM from an image here.
2. Create via classic portal:
   -> I can't select a new storage account so the .vhd of the new VM will be located in the existing storage account
3. Using [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Copy-a-Virtual-Machine-83d192a5) to copy the existing VM. -> I got this error: `New-AzureVM : ConflictError: A disk with name xxxxx is currently in use by virtual
   machine xxx running within hosted service xxx, deployment xxx.` Yeah, of course the disk is in use by a VM; I thought this script deals with this fact and copies both VM *and* vhd?!
4. Create a new (empty) storage account and copy the existing .vhd & .status blob files from the old into the new storage account (I used [this tutorial](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axilicious/archive/2014/05/12/windows-azure-copy-vhd-between-subscriptions)). Both files were copied successfully. -> Now I wanted to create a new VM "from existing VHD" (via classic portal) but the new (copied) VHD doesn't appear here.

So I'm out of ideas how to clone a VM with my requirements. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know Azure PS this can be done in these steps.

Step 1. Move all the vhds to your newstorge account which you have already done. great !

Step 2. convert the vhds to disk using Azure PS-

`Add-AzureDisk -DiskName "YourVHDName" -MediaLocation "https://NewStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/YourVHDName.vhd" -os "Windows"` (for os disk )

```
Add-AzureDisk -DiskName "YourVHDName" 
-MediaLocation "https://NewStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/YourVHDName.vhd"
```

Step 3. Most Important spin vm using OS disk-

```
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId "YourSubscriptionId"-CurrentStorageAccountName "NewStorageAccount"

$vm=New-AzureVMConfig -DiskName "YourVHDName" -InstanceSize "YourInstanceSize" -Name "YourVMName" 

New-AzureVM -Location "YourLocation" -ServiceName "YourNewService" -VNetName "YourNewvNet" -VM $vm -verbose
```

4. Step 3 will spin vm for you. Now simply attach the disk to vm which you have already created in step 2

Comment: Oh no I rated too fast: I was able to create my VM, but I can't start it. I get: "The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request."